# tinymce not working when loading page two or more times

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

when i load preview of page second time in the same or other div tinyMCE editor not working anymore

Using code like this:

```
$('#div1').load('page_url', function(){
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "#my_div_ID",
            inline: true,
            toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent",
            mode : "textareas",
            element_format : "html",
            plugins: "autolink link",
            menubar: false
        });
    });
```

another is almost the same:

```
$('#div2').load('page_url', function(){
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "#my_div_ID",
            inline: true,
            toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent",
            mode : "textareas",
            element_format : "html",
            plugins: "autolink link",
            menubar: false
        });
    });
```

and i have few loads like this, depends on clicks on the other elements in page.
Is it possible and if yes - how, to make working tinymce on each load?

P.S. i was trying to empty #div1 and #div2 with `$('#div1').empty();` before load but still no result.

Also I #my_div_ID is always the same, and I can't change it..

Comment: getting any console errors???

Comment: nope... just see that it tries to load the page, it loads, but tinymce not working.. 
and I have in these function another crop image function and it's working correctly to all loads :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the solution for myself:
 before load the page I am removing tinyMCE and emptying `#div1` and `div2` like this:

```
tinymce.remove("#my_div_ID");
$('#div1, #div2').empty();
```

and only then loading the page.